# How to manage volume's rights

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using Docker to run a background service analysis my dev directory. I'm using `docker run -v /host/project:/media/analysis:rw` on my container to run it.

However, this commande cause one problem, files from this volume belongs to UID 1000 (root), while I'd like to open it with my service. I'm using `chown user:user -R /media/analysis` however this require to be run commands from the docker container and I'd like to avoid the user to execute commandes once he ran the container.

A second problematic is that, even if I run a script with the `run`command, as it's a developper directory, new files will be certainly added, and I discovered that creating new files on the host are seen as "root" files for Docker which mean I need also to update the volumes rights when the service is processing.

Regards,
Waldo

**UPDATE :**

I thought about an other way to solve my problem, it works but as a beginner I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do it.

On my Dockerfile, I add an `ENTRYPOINT script.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
olduser=$(id -u sonarqube)
oldgroup=$(id -g sonarqube)

usermod -u ${USER_ID} sonarqube \;
groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} sonarqube ;

find / -group ${oldgroup} -exec chgrp -h sonarqube {} \;
find / -user ${olduser} -exec chown -h sonarqube {} \;
```

Then, I use the following command to run my container :

`docker run -v /project:/analysis:rw -e USER_ID=$(id -u) GROUP_ID=$(id -g) image`

Answer (score -1):

You can set the owning user/group from the Dockerfile.

```
RUN mkdir -p /somedir && chown -R someone:someone /somedir
VOLUME ["/somedir"]
```

There are other ways to do this, so something to read ;) https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259

Comment: If I do so, I'll still have problem to make an user non-root receiving the right to read/write on my hosts files, no ?

Comment: On new volumes the initial owner is the owner of the directory, but if you use an existing volume the permissions are used from that existing volume.